# How to change colormap of indexed image to HSV colormap in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am using an indexed image.How do I programatically obtain the pixel intensity values obtained by changing the colormap to hsv in the imtool? Is there a way to change the colormap of the indexed image to hsv(256)?

I am new to MATLAB, kindly help!
I have attached the image below:
[image]

Which channel does the imtool display and  what does the value '91' in the imtool stand for? How do I obtain this value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Pixel info at the bottom displays the following information:
Pixel info: (X, Y): Pixel Value

Here, we have pixel value of 91 at (309, 510). 91 is the pixel intensity in a range of values (mostly 0 to 255). Only 1 channel is being read because it is a grayscale image.

You can create a hsv image out of an RGB image but it doesnt make sense to talk of a hsv conversion for a gray scale image. What you have is a grayscale image.

Comment: You are right. The image has only a single channel. But why does the command window display a different value [i.e. 222] but in the imtool the value is 91?

Comment: oh! now i see it... interesting. Well, in MATLAB, when you say A(r, c) you are indexing the rth row and cth column. which is actually pixel location (c, r). So, the pixel info at (309, 510) will be found at A(510, 309).

Comment: Yes! Just figured it out. Its quite confusing to code now! :P